# htaccess 301 redirects with multiple rules and utm parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, utm

I am trying to create a redirect for 3 different situations including adding parameters or UTM tags but I can't figure it out. I need the following redirects:

1. Redirect Course urls (notice course changes to courses):

`Mydomain.com/rodkits/course/lesson1` redirect to `Mydomain.com/courses/lesson1`
`Mydomain.com/rodkits/course/lesson2` redirect to `Mydomain.com/courses/lesson2` etc for multiple lessons

2. Former Course homepage 
   `Mydomain.com/rodkits/` redirect to `Mydomain.com/courses/fishing-rod-building-course/`
3. Static Pages including utm tags
   `Mydomain.com/rodkits/page1` redirect to `Mydomain.com/page1`
   `Mydomain.com/rodkits/page2/?utm_source=qld%20s.....` redirect to `Mydomain.com/page2/?utm_source=qld%20s.....` etc for multiple pages

Everything seems to work fine unless the utm tags are added to the urls then anything with a utm tag is redirected to Mydomain.com/courses/fishing-rod-building-course(whatever the url was less rodkits)
For example `Mydomain.com/rodkits/page1/?utm_source=qld%20s.....` gets redirect to `Mydomain.com/courses/fishing-rod-building-coursepage1/?utm_source=qld%20s.....`

How can I fix this

My htacces:

```
# BEGIN 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /rodkits/    /courses/fishing-rod-building-course
RewriteRule ^rodkits/course/(.*)$ /courses/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^rodkits/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
# END 301 Redirects
```

Comment: You mean `Mydomain.com/rodkits/page1/?utm_source=…` gets redirected, not `Mydomain.com/page1/?utm_source=…`, right? (Because /page1/ being affected would not make any sense here, all your patterns start with `rodkits`.)

Comment: The Redirect directive works based on checking for path prefixes. You are redirecting anything that _starts with_ `/rodkits/` with that line already, and whatever suffix came after that match, gets appended to the target URL. Don’t use Redirect here, instead handle that case using a RewriteRule as well.

Comment: @misorude you were correct with the first comment I have updated the question. So how do I get the first redirect rule to only affect the original course home page i.e end in `/rodkits/` or just `/rodkits` because I dont want this rule to affect anything with additional parameters after the `/`

Comment: As I said, replace Redirect with another RewriteRule. `RewriteRule ^rodkits/?$ /courses/fishing-rod-building-course [R=301,NC,L]`